# My example.downloadURL gives back an undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am simply trying to test uploading images and I want to display the image, that is uploadoaded.
My code looks like this:

```
function uploadFile(files){
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(); //this references the firebase storage

    const horseRef = storageRef.child("horse.jpg");

    const file = files.item(0); //will return a list so lets take the first item

    const task = horseRef.put(file); //to upload the file we call the put file
    console.log(task);

    task.then(snapshot => { //returns a buncha data including a snapshot url
        const url = snapshot.downloadURL
        document.getElementById("upload").setAttribute("src", url)
    });

}
```

But the snapshot.downloadURL is giving back an undefined. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any `downloadURL` property on the snapshot which is an [UploadTaskSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot). You need to use `getDownloadURL()` method on the storage reference to get the URL. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
task.then(async (snapshot) => { 
  const url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadUrl()
  document.getElementById("upload").setAttribute("src", url)
});
```

Comment: Wow, then my tutorial was misleading. Thank you very much!!